# How can I restrict number of choices in a full factorial design using dcreate?

Tags: stata

I'm faced with a problem with the code below where Stata MP gives me 2700 observations where it should only create 60 observations.

This code is intended to create a full factorial design for a discrete choice experiment with 30 sets on each block with two alternatives in each set, combining the total of 60 choice sets for two blocks.

```
clear
matrix levmat = 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3 
genfact, levels(levmat) 
 
rename x1 AA
rename x2 AB 
rename x3 AC
rename x4 AD 
rename x5 AE
rename x6 AF

recode TravTime (1=-20) (2=-10) (3=0) (4=10) (5=20)
recode CouncilTax (1=-20) (2=-10) (3=0) (4=10) (5=20)
recode PrimDist (1=-10) (2=0) (3=10)
 
matrix b = -0.01, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
dcreate i.AA i.AB i.AC i.AD i.AE i.AF, nalt(2) nset(30) bmat(b)
blockdes block, nblock(2)

list, separator(2)
```

I expect the number of all combinations to be 60 choice sets only instead of 2700

Comment: `di 5*5*4*3*3*3` returns 2700, so where does 60 come from?

Comment: 60 comes from nalt(2)*nset(30)=60

Comment: Also dcreate command should only create subset of all possible combinations based on my "nalt" and "nset" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`genfact` produces the full factorial design, which as Nick points out has 2700 rows/alternatives. -`dcreate` creates the design for the choice experiment, which has 30 choice sets with two alternatives each, so 60 rows.

There are a few problems with the code:

a) There are too few coefficients in the b matrix as there are 17 effects to be estimated when all of the attributes are dummy coded.

b) The `recode` commands produce an error as they refer to variables that are not included in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your and nick's responses